# gevent queue failed with LoopExit

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, gevent

I want to use python gevent library to implement one producer and multiple consumers server. There is my attempt:

```
class EmailValidationServer():
   def __init__(self):
      self.queue = Queue()
   def worker(self):
      while True:
          json = self.queue.get()
   def handler(self,socket,address):
      fileobj = socket.makefile()
      content = fileobj.read(max_read)
      contents = json.loads(content)
      for content in contents:
          self.queue.put(content)
   def daemon(self,addr='127.0.0.1',num_thread=5):
      pool = Pool(1000)
      server = StreamServer((addr, 6000),self.handler,spawn=pool) # run
      pool = ThreadPool(num_thread)
      for _ in range(num_thread):
          pool.spawn(self.worker)
      server.serve_forever()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    email_server = EmailValidationServer()
    email_server.daemon()
```

I used the queue from gevent.queue.Queue. It gives me the error information:

```
LoopExit: This operation would block forever
(<ThreadPool at 0x7f08c80eef50 0/4/5>,
 <bound method EmailValidationServer.worker of <__main__.EmailValidationServer instance at 0x7f08c8dcd998>>) failed with LoopExit
```

Problem: But when I change the Queue from gevent's implementation to python build-in library, it works. I do not know the reason, I guess it's supported to have difference between their implementation. I do not know the reason why gevent does not allow infinite wait. Is there anyone can give an explanation? Thanks advance

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you could use the `gevent.queue.JoinableQueue()` instead of Python's built-in `Queue()`. You can refer to the official queue guide for API Usages (http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html)

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        try:
            do_work(item)
        finally:
            q.task_done()

q = JoinableQueue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     gevent.spawn(worker)

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()  # block until all tasks are done
```

If you met the exceptions again, you'd better get fully understand the principle of Gevent corouinte control flow ...Once you get the point, that was not a big deal. :)

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan thans for formatting my code blocks :)